# Teechart and PDF

Tags: pdf, teechart

I'm testing the last demo version to know the possibility of integration with our products.

When I try to export to pdf, I get a gray square that does not appear in the preview.
I tried to change options on the component but without success.

Is this behavior a bug or is it because I use a trial version?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello @user2455861 could you specify the version of TeeChart (VCL,ACTIVEX,JAVA,.NET) you are using? Thanks,

Comment: Also tell us how the "gray square" looks. Is it the whole chart or just a part of it? Show an image if possible, and post an example too